# Spatie/Laravel-Permission - Agregar un campo a la tabla "ROLES"

Tags: laravel

Relacioné la tabla "roles" con mi tabla "empresa", es decir, en la tabla "roles", tengo el campo "id_empresa", en la vista, están los campos necesarios y el select de la empresa pero al querer guardar los datos, me arroja el siguiente error:  "The given role or permission should use guard web instead of Empresas.

No entiendo el porqué, ya que en la tabla "roles", se guarda por defecto en el campo guard_name la palabra "web".